# C# Expression with collection item properties - access member names

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I am building an SDK for building HTTP Queries to a certain system where I need to specify in the query string which properties of a model I want to include.

For example `https://system/api/projects/1?fields=name,description`

I want the SDK to be strongly typed, so I have query builder classes which allow specifying the query as

`new ProjectBuilder(1, f => f.Name, f => f.Description)`

That works very nice even for complex tree of nested objects, e.g. `f => f.ProjectTemplate.Location.Owner.Email`

**The only problem is with collections**, e.g.

```
public class Task
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
  //lots of other stuff
}

public string Project
{
   public string Description {get;set;}
  //lots of other stuff
   public List<Task> Tasks {get;set;}
}
```

When I need to retrieve `Project`'s `Description` and names of all `Tasks` in the `Project`, the query string would have to be as follows:

`https://system/api/projects/1?fields=description,tasks.name`

I cannot define an expression like that:

`new ProjectBuilder(1, f => f.Tasks.Name)`, the syntax seem to require `f.Tasks[0].Name`.

**Can I have the same nice expression-type syntax with collection members (and further nested objects)?**

The  code that I use for member access from expression is below (slighty simplified):

```
        public static string Evaluate<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
        {
            if (expression.Body is MemberExpression body)
            {
                return EvaluateExpressionTree(body);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Invalid expression. Expected Member expression, e.g. p=>p.Description");
            }
        }
            private static string EvaluateExpressionTree(MemberExpression root)
            {
                if (root.Expression is MemberExpression nested)
                {
                    var nestedProperty = EvaluateExpressionTree(nested);
                    var thisProperty = root.Member.Name;
                    return nestedProperty + "." + thisProperty;
                }
                else if (root.Expression is MethodCallExpression call)
                {
                    //that's where I get when using the Tasks[0] syntax
                 }
                else
                {
                    return GetMemberName(root);
                }
            }
```

I was able to get to the point of finding the generic type from the collection when the expression was accessing a collection element, but from that point I cannot rebuild the further elements of the expression...

Comment: I don't have the experience with it to put together an answer, but have you considered looking at OData to do this?

Comment: You'll definitely need a different way to do it. One way is to use a fluent interface like Linq does. Or how Entity Framework works with includes (e.g. `Include(x => x.Parent).ThenInclude(y => y.Child)`. Alternatively drop this whole thing and use OData or GraphQL.

Comment: @DavidG - Not sure if these (graphql & odata) would be possible, as I have no influence over the design of the REST API that I am querying - what I am after is creating a strongly-typed SDK with a nice fluent syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this for my kind of problem. Not saying this is the way of handling expressions with collection properties, but question is specific, and so is the answer:)

#### Overview

The solution was to

- stringify the expression
- tokenize it
- remove noise
- evaluate parts by getting PropertyInfo by Reflection
- keep track of the current type within the expression tree to get correct results

That allows me to have a nice fluent API for strong typed generation of query strings, as visible below.

#### Code

**Usage**

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void ProjectExpression_NestedType_CollectionAccess()
    {
        //arrange
        ProjectBuilder builder = new ProjectBuilder("000",
                f => f.Name,
                f => f.Workflow.TaskConfigurations,
                f => f.Workflow.TaskConfigurations[0].TaskTemplate.TaskType)
            ;

        //act
        string stringified = builder.BuildFullRequestUri();

        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual("projects/000?fields=name,workflow.taskConfigurations,workflow.taskConfigurations.taskTemplate.taskType", stringified);
    }
```

**Implementation:**

The caller code that takes the function params:

```
 protected ProjectBuilder(params Expression<Func<Project, object>>[] propertiesToInclude)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Expression<Func<Project, object>> expression in propertiesToInclude)
        {
            values.Add(ExpressionEvaluator.Evaluate(expression));
        }
        this.AddProperties(values);
    }
```

And the expression evaluator that takes each param and transforms it nicely.

```
internal static class ExpressionEvaluator
{
    public static string Evaluate<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            List<string> parts = GetExpressionParts(expression);

            List<Type> expressionTreeTypes = new List<Type>() { typeof(T)  };
            foreach (string part in parts) 
            {
                PropertyInfo member = expressionTreeTypes.Last().GetProperty(part);
                if (member != null)
                {
                    AddValueFromJsonAttributeOrPropertyName<T>(member, result);
                    UpdateLastUsedType<T>(member, expressionTreeTypes);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Expression [{expression.Body}] is not valid. Failed to resolve: [{part}]");
                }
            }
            return string.Join(".", result);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid expression. Expected Member expression, e.g. p=>p.Description");
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetExpressionParts<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        var stringified = expression.Body.ToString();
        //skip the first part of expression - e.g. (f=>f.) - skip 'f.
        //also skip collection accessors
        return stringified.Split('.').Where(x => !x.Contains("get_Item(")).Skip(1).ToList();
    }

    private static void UpdateLastUsedType<T>(PropertyInfo member, List<Type> expressionTreeTypes)
    {
        //make sure that in case of primitive types we don't change the type
        if (member.PropertyType.Assembly == typeof(Project).Assembly && member.PropertyType != expressionTreeTypes.Last())
        {
            expressionTreeTypes.Add(member.PropertyType);
        }
        else if (member.PropertyType.IsGenericType) // in case of collection properties, extract the nested type 
        {
            expressionTreeTypes.Add(member.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First());
        }
    }

    private static void AddValueFromJsonAttributeOrPropertyName<T>(MemberInfo member, List<string> result)
    {
        var attr = member.CustomAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))?.ConstructorArguments?
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr?.Value?.ToString()))
        {
            result.Add(attr?.Value?.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(member.Name[0].ToString().ToLower() + member.Name.Substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```